# Common words with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the common words from a string.

I found out this method:
http://jsbin.com/nufimudivu/1/edit

```
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = (wordCounts["_" + words[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
```

The problem is that I want that my output to be like

```
{
   {
         'word': '_lipsum',
         'count': Number here
   }, 
   {
          <!-- other word here -->
   }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/bivoposijo/2/edit

Comment: The wanted output is invalid JS. You need an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply convert the output to the format you want:

```
var wordArr = [];
for (var word in wordCounts) {
  wordArr.push({
    word: word,
    count: wordCounts[word]
  })  
}
console.log(wordArr)
```

Comment: Thanks, works. http://jsbin.com/hofefudoqa/1/edit?js,console - Can I wrap this in a object not array?

Comment: @Marius The format you ask is invalid, because the objects don't have keys. So that's a list (array) of objects, not an object of objects.